# node npm local install puts files into ~/node_modules

Tags: node.js, installation, package, npm

When I install a package using **npm install** command, it installs the files into ~/node_modules. When I run the package, I get **command not found** error.

How do I install it into a folder where I want to call the package?

Comment: You can also use npm install -g to install modules globally. That may work for what you need.

Comment: I try to avoid it because it requires a root access.

Comment: can you show some example code?

Comment: @zeMirco // well...I just run  npm install [packagename]. That's all.

Comment: and what code did you use to "run the package". Did you use the command line or did you try it from a .js file?

Comment: @zeMirco // Can you even run npm install from js? I didn't know that..I used terminal. npm install uglify-js.

Comment: ah..i guess you can...using nodejs

Comment: now i get it. the `npm install` command causes the error `command not found`. I thought `requiring` the installed package would cause the error. Looks like `node.js` and `npm` is not installed correctly. Try to reinstall.

Comment: reinstalled; still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
npm install <name_of_package> -g
```

This will install the package globally. If the program is in your `PATH`, then you should be able to run it just like any other program.

For example:
`npm install nodemon -g`

then run `nodemon` from the command prompt, and it should work

Comment: i'm trying to avoid -g option; it requires root access. Is this only way?

Comment: No, you could install it locally without the `-g`, but you'll have to explicitly call the pathname or place the path into your PATH environment variable, just like any other program.

Comment: // may be I was confused. I remember it working without the fullpath. Thanks!

Comment: well, you could probably do a relative path, too. Most programs would be just like running any other kind of script, except that you won't have to do something like `node <program>`. Since, the program will have a `#!/usr/local/bin/node` in the first line, or something similar.

Comment: Simply add ``./node_modules/.bin`` to your ``PATH``, and all the commands installed locally by ``npm`` will be available.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install it globally, the right answer is the last comment in the checked answer:

Simply add ./node_modules/.bin to your PATH, and all the commands installed locally by npm will be available. – H_I Dec 24 '12 at 9:54

You can add it to your path in your .bashrc file using the command:
export PATH="$PATH:/home/login/node_modules/.bin"

Reload your .bashrc using:
source .bashrc